# Angular2 Error as Elements can't be read

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

Here i have a Simple Html Reader Elements as like

```
 <input type="button" value="Submit" (click)="Login(LoginObj)" />

     Login(e) {
           var  UserName = e.target.elements[0].value;
            var  Password = e.target.elements[1].value;
    }
```

Here i'm getting Error as elements cant Read

Comment: Can you provide exact error that which element can't read?

Comment: Instead of reading the username and password values using event, you should bind properties to the inputs

Comment: Sorry for the Late Response @jParma   This is Error Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined

Comment: Even when i'm typing e. its not showing Intelligence

Comment: Whatever you are passing as your LoginObj doesn't have the `target` property. Please include more of your code.